# Laravel 5.1 users, roles and actions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating an application using Laravel 5.1 with *users*, *roles* and *actions*.

The table setup is like so:

**user**

```
id    name
1     John Smith
2     Fred Smith
```

**role**

```
id    name
1     Administrator
2     Customer
```

**role_user**

```
user_id    role_id
1          1
2          1
```

**action**

```
id    name        description                    path
1     dashboard   ability to access dashboard    /admin
2     editAdmin   ability to edit admins         /admin/users/administrators/{id}/edit
```

**action_role**

```
action_id    role_id
1            1
2            1
```

The `user` table holds ALL users on the site, including administrators and customers.

The `role` table holds all the possible roles a user can have.  For example *Administrator* or *Customer*.

The `role_user` table is a pivot table which links `role` to `user`.

The `action` table lists all of the actions possible (i.e. urls or routes) on the app.

The `action_role` is a pivot table which links `action` to `role`.

So to summarise:

- Users have roles
- Roles have actions
- A user can have many roles
- A role can have many actions

I want to have a middleware setup which checks on page load if the user has permissions to view the current page.  In order to do this, I need to be able to access a users actions, using a call like this:

```
$user->roles()->actions();
```

How do I setup my eloquent relationships to support this kind of call?

**UPDATE**

My relationships are setup like so in my models:

**User**

```
/**
 * The roles that belong to the user.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\Role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Role**

```
/**
 * The actions that belong to the role.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function actions() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\Action');
}

/**
 * The users that belong to the role.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\User');
}
```

**Action**

```
/**
 * The roles that belong to the action.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function roles() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\Role');
}
```

Comment: What more are you trying to achieve aside from the code you have already provided?

Comment: My questions are at the bottom of the post.  I basically just want to check if the user has permission to view the current page.  What is the best way of achieveing that with the above table setup?

Comment: Laravel 5 or laravel 5.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent does not have a `HasManyThrough` relationship across 2 pivot tables.

---

**1.** You can get the actions by lazy eager loading the roles and actions, then extracting them:

```
$actions = $user->load('roles.actions')->roles->pluck('actions')->collapse()->unique();
```

---

**2.** You can check the action directly in the database, using a `whereHas` constraint:

```
$allowed = $user->roles()->whereHas('actions', function ($query) use ($action) {
    $query->where('name', $action);
})->exists();
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89821/discussion-between-v4n1ll4-and-joseph-silber).

Comment: BTW, I just released a new package named [Bouncer](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer). It's a very simple roles and abilities system for Laravel. You might like it. Even if you don't end up using it, at least take a look at [the queries](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/blob/master/src/Clipboard.php#L186-L227). You might learn something :)

Answer (score 1):

For handling user, user roles and user permissions you can simply use [Toddish](https://github.com/Toddish/Verify-L4) package.

There are lot of things this package does for you. like:

```
$user->is('Your Defined Role');
$user->can('add_user');
$user->level(7);
```

For installation just read it's documentation.

Comment: As I'm building quite a large application is prefer to have the flexibility of building my own. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There's nothing to be worried about flexibility with this package. 
All this package does is just creating DB tables and migrations for you. And few php classes with some handy functions.
You can easily develop or customise this package as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have mentioned that your Eloquent models (and their relationships) are set up, I am assuming that you have the following in your application already:

**User model**

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role');
    }
}
```

**Role model**

```
class Role extends Eloquent {
    public function actions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Action');
    }
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

**Action model**

```
class Action extends Eloquent{
    public function roles(){ 
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role'); 
    }
}
```

Given the above set properly, you can't certainly make a call like the following as Laravel will assume you're making a call to a Query Builder method or whatever [which in fact doesn't exist]:

```
$userActions = App\Models\User::find(1)->roles()->actions();
```

Instead, you have to use Laravel's *magical* [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method to query relations where multiple nested relations are involved.

Now, having the user's `id` and the current allowed `action` [*which indeed can be utilized in your middleware*], it can be determined whether the user is allowed to see the page:

```
$hasAccess = App\Models\User::whereHas('roles.actions', function($q) use ($id, $action){
    $q->where('users.id', $id);
    $q->where('actions.name', $action);
})->get()->toArray();
if($hasAccess){      // or `count($hasAccess) > 0`. The former will work since any number > 0 evaluates to true in PHP
    //user has access
}
```

Notice the *nesting* of relationships with `.`.

---

#### ***Relationship Existence in Laravel***:

In Laravel the existence of a relationship between models is determined with `has` and `whereHas` methods. The `has` method is used to only determine *if a relationship exists*, e.g. by executing `App\User::has('roles')->get()` you'll always get a list/collection of users which at least have any *roles*. 
More power to this can be added with `whereHas` with which you can add `where` clauses to the actual query.

Comment: How can I select the `actions.name` value so the array also contains that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is how I solved this.

I didn't use an actions table. Just **users**, **roles** and the **user_role** table.
After the solution, I pass my custom middleware a role array to every route I create like:

```
Route::get('insights',[
    'as'=>'insights',
    **'middleware'=>['access.level'],**
    **'roles'=>['admin','customer'],**
    'uses'=>'CustomersController@index'
    ]);
```

Files modified:
app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php
**Custom middleware:** CheckAccessLevel
app\Http\Kernel.php
app\Http\routes.php

**Controller.php**
In this file, I wanted to eager load the current logged in user with his roles and make it a global variable in all views as **{{currentUser}}** and in all my controllers as **"$this->currentUser"**. this is the code:

```
    protected $currentUser;

public function __construct() {
    if(isset(Auth::user()->username)){

        $this->currentUser = User::with('roles')->where(['username' => Auth::user()->username])->first();

        // Share this property with all the views and controllers in your application.
        view()->share('currentUser', $this->currentUser);
    }
}
```

**Custom Middleware:** CheckAccessLevel.php

Over here in the middleware, I retrieve the roles array passed to the route and and also the roles assigned to the current user. 
After i get these variables, I intersect them to see if there is a match before I pass the user on. check the code below:

```
//if user is not logged in, show them where to login :)
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->route('user::login');
    }


    //Otherwise get the roles for that route
    $get_route_action = $request->route()->getAction();
    $get_route_roles = $get_route_action['roles'];

    //Eager load the user with their list of roles
    $eager_user = User::with('roles')->where(['id'=>$request->user()->id])->first();
    $user_roles = $eager_user->roles->pluck('role_name')->toArray();

    //intersect the users roles with the route roles to see if there is a match
    foreach ($user_roles as $user_role){
        if(in_array($user_role, $get_route_roles)){
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

**Kernel.php**
over here, i register my route as "access.level" inside the route middleware group

**Route.php**
then whenever I create a route, I just pass in the allowed role names to it and voala! It works for me..

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

You need a HasManyThrough relationship here.. Here's something to get you started.

Judging by your given tables I see it has a one-to-many relationship with user and roles. While action and roles also has many-to-many relationship.

But first you need to create models for each entities(user,role,action) to follow the MVC structure. You could easily make these models from the command line using the Laravel's artisan with this command.

```
php artisan make:model User
```

Make sure to also add or change columns in the newly created migrations. Assuming you also have your pivot tables set up for the 3 tables, you can now add the relationships.

```
class User extends Model {

//
protected $table = 'users';

/*
*   @var table
*
*/

public function action()
{

    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Action', 'App\Role');
}

}
```

Now you have a **HasManyThrough** relationship. you can query like this directly no need to include role.

```
   //this
    $actions = User::find(1)->action();
    //instead of 
    $actions = User::find(1)->role()->action();
    //this will return all actions available to a user with id of 1
```

**NOTE** I also suggest you make your role and user models to be on a one to one relationship.

Comment: when I try the code above, I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::action()`.  The role() seems to work, but it doesn't like it when I use `action()`.

Comment: I do not think `action()` is callable through the `user` model.

Comment: can you try changing the function name of action?

Comment: If I change to actions i still get the same.

Comment: do you have pivot table for action and role?

Comment: Yes role_user and action_role

Comment: hmmm did you call action through role? like my example?

Comment: Yes, role() is working fine when I remove the action() call. But when I add action() I get the undefined method error.  Are you sure that role()->action() should work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89519/discussion-between-gokigooooks-and-v4n1ll4).

Comment: try this now @V4n1ll4