# Laravel nested relationship where

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am building a system that has users.  Users have roles and roles have actions.  My models are setup like so:

**User**

```
/**
 * The roles that belong to the user.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\Role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Role**

```
/**
 * The actions that belong to the role.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function actions() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\Action')->withPivot('path');
}

/**
 * The users that belong to the role.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\User');
}
```

**Action**

```
/**
 * The roles that belong to the action.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function roles() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\Role');
}
```

I am trying search the users actions using the following:

```
$user->whereHas('roles.actions', function($query) use ($id, $path, $method){ 
        $query->where('user.id', $id);
        $query->where('action.path', $path);
        $query->where('action.method', $method);
})->get();
```

However, for some reason the object returned is empty (no rows returned).  If I remove the `$query->where('action.path', $path);` it works, but that is pointless because I need that part.

The SQL that gets generated is:

```
select * from `user` 
    where `user`.`cust_id` = 1 
    and (
            select count(*) from `role` 
            inner join `role_user` on `role`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` 
            where `role`.`cust_id` = 1 
            and `role_user`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` 
            and 
            (
                select count(*) from `action` 
                inner join `action_role` on `action`.`id` = `action_role`.`action_id` 
                where `action`.`cust_id` = 1 
                and `action_role`.`role_id` = `role`.`id` 
                and `user`.`id` = 1 
                and `action`.`path` = '/admin/users/administrators/{id}/changePassword' 
                and `action`.`method` = 'GET' 
                and `action`.`cust_id` = 1
            ) >= 1 
            and `role`.`cust_id` = 1
        ) >= 1
```

My users table contains the following data:

```
id    cust_id    name
1     1          John Smith
```

My action table contains the following data:

```
id    cust_id    path                                               method
1     1          /admin/users/administrators/{id}/changePassword    GET
```

**Why is this not working?**

Comment: Using my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551662/laravel-5-1-users-roles-and-actions/32593899#32593899), and I suppose it was useful, but didn't consider _voting up_ at least. :(

Comment: What does your `$user` variable have, is it `App\User::all()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand how that's a valid query because you are querying on a column in the `users` table in the subquery which is not joining on anything pertaining to users.

Try this instead.

```
$user->whereHas('roles.actions', function($query) use ( $path, $method){
    $query->where('path', $path);
    $query->where('method', $method);
})->find($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `->withPivot('path');` and try again

Answer (score 0):

As noted in your question, and the other one ***[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551662/laravel-5-1-users-roles-and-actions/32593899#32593899)*** `path` is NOT an extra attribute of your pivot table `action_role` - holding the relationship between models `Role` and `Action`.

Instead it's an attribute of the `action` table. Hence, using `withPivot('path')` you're defining that extra attribute on the `pivot` (i.e. `action_role`) that doesn't exist and therefore is not at all necessary.

Regarding the empty set you get if you include the line `$query->where('action.path', $path)`, the most probable reason is that *incorrect* OR `null` value is provided in your `$path` variable. Double check to see if it has the right value.

---

**Note:** *As far as I know, you can't execute `whereHas` on the `$user` like that (although I'm not quite sure what it holds).*
Even if the `$user` is a collection of users (*obtained by `App\Models\User::all()`*), the appropriate approach to using `whereHas` is to use it on a model like `App\User::whereHas(...` or a along with a relation.